# How to get Magento Payone active payment methods?

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, payment, magento-1.9

We use Payone with our Magento shop. And we want to show our users warnings in their cart when their total amount is too large for a certain payment method.

That is why I want to check the total amount against each payment method max order value.

But somehow I can not reach the correct data.

When I try to get them by Payones config:

```
$methods = Mage::helper('payone_core/config')->getConfigPayment($store);
```

I get an `object->array` with all methods, but they are protected. So I can not use them in my cart module.

What is a clean way to get Payones payment methods (all active methods with their max_order_value)?

**Edit:**

I tried following code, but it still says:

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property
>   Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment::$methods in
>   /pathToClass/CtaB2c/Helper/Data.php on line 20

```
class CtaB2c_Helper_Data extends Payone_Core_Helper_Config {
    public function getConfigPayment($store) {
        return parent::getConfigPayment($store);
    }

    public function showPaymentRestrictions() {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $store = $quote->getStoreId();
        $total = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal();
        $methods = $this->getConfigPayment($store);
        $methods = $methods->methods; //error occurs here: member has protected access

        $avaibleMethods = array();

        foreach ($methods AS $mid => $method) {
            $minTotal = $method->minOrderTotal;
            $maxTotal = $method->maxOrderTotal;

            if($minTotal <= $total && $maxTotal >= $total) {
                $avaibleMethods[$mid] = $method->code;
            }
        }

        return $avaibleMethods;
    }
}
```

I know, there is no check if this payment method is avaible, but actually I just want know if maxOrderTotal is bigger than payment methods max_order_total. And of course I do not need this extra function. I could call `parent::getConfigPayment($store)` in my function as well.

*Edit 2*
This is the object I get from `getConfigPayment()`:

```
object(Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment)#<a number> (1) {
  ["methods":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    [<a number>]=>
    object(Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment_Method)#<a number> (38) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      string(1) "a number"
      ["scope":protected]=>
      string(6) "stores"
      ["scope_id":protected]=>
      string(1) "<a number>"
      ["code":protected]=>
      string(15) "advance_payment"
      ["name":protected]=>
      string(8) "Vorkasse"
      ["sort_order":protected]=>
      string(1) "<a number>"
      ["enabled":protected]=>
      string(1) "<a number>"
      ["fee_config":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["mode":protected]=>
      string(4) "test"
      ["use_global":protected]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["mid":protected]=>
      string(5) "<a number>"
      ["portalid":protected]=>
      string(7) "<a number>"
      ["aid":protected]=>
      string(5) "<a number>"
      ["key":protected]=>
      string(16) "<a key>"
      ["allowspecific":protected]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["specificcountry":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["allowedCountries":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "DE"
        [1]=>
        string(2) "AT"
      }
      ["request_type":protected]=>
      string(16) "preauthorization"
      ["invoice_transmit":protected]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["types":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["klarna_config":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["klarna_campaign_code":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["paypal_express_image":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["check_cvc":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["check_bankaccount":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["bankaccountcheck_type":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["message_response_blocked":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["sepa_country":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["sepa_de_show_bank_data":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["sepa_mandate_enabled":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["sepa_mandate_download_enabled":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["customer_form_data_save":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["is_deleted":protected]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["minValidityPeriod":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["minOrderTotal":protected]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["maxOrderTotal":protected]=>
      string(4) "1000"
      ["parent":protected]=>
      string(1) "<a number>"
      ["currency_convert":protected]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the payone_core/config class YourNameSpace_Module_Helper_Payone extends ThePayOneNamespace_Payone_Core_Config and basically get any method to be public

```
class YourNameSpace_Module_Helper_Payone extends ThePayOneNamespace_Payone_Core_Config

   public function someProtectedParentMethod()
   {
       return parent::someProtectedParentMethod();
   }
}
```

The above will allow you to use any protected method and get the data you are after.

Comment: This does not work. As a child class I can not access the values. But I will have to check the object - I guess it is a model and I need to extend from this one?

Comment: The above solution will allow you access to protected methods from the parent class that you would not be able to access normally. Inside a public function of your class you can cal a parent method that is protected and get it's data. That will work, i am not sure what is not working, but getting access to parent protected methods by a class that extends the parent is possible.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out that I did not use the correct class to extend from. But anyway - I guess that would be the wrong way. As you can see my edit, I get a whole model returned and it has getter and setter for all values.

Answer (score 0):

This is hopefully the Magento way to get information about Payones Payment methods. You should call `setPaymentRestrictionNoticeMessage()` somewhere in your controller.

```
class YourModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    /**
     * Returns array of methods that will not work with current max order value.
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPaymentsWithRestrictions() {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $store = $quote->getStoreId();
        $total = $quote->getBaseGrandTotal();

        /**
         * @var Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment $model
         */
        $model = Mage::helper('payone_core/config')->getConfigPayment($store);
        $methods = $model->getMethods();

        $restrictedMethods = array();

        foreach ($methods AS $mid => $method) {
            /**
             * @var Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment_Method $method
             */
            $minTotal = $method->getMinOrderTotal();
            $maxTotal = $method->getMaxOrderTotal();
            $isEnabled = $method->getEnabled();

            if($isEnabled && ($minTotal > $total || $maxTotal < $total)) {
                $restrictedMethods[$mid] = $method;
            }
        }

        return $restrictedMethods;
    }

    /**
     * Sets notification message with information about payment methods
     * that will not work.
     */
    public function setPaymentRestrictionNoticeMessage() {
        $restrictedMethodModels = $this->getPaymentsWithRestrictions();

        $restrictedMethods = array();

        foreach ($restrictedMethodModels AS $methodModel) {
            /**
             * @var Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment_Method $methodModel
             */
            $restrictedMethods[] = $methodModel->getName();
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice(
            Mage::helper('checkout')->__(
                'Your order value is too high for following payment methods: ' . implode(', ', $restrictedMethods)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying this is the answer?

Comment: @Harry that is what works for me. But I still do not know if this is the correct way of Magento. At least I use Payones methods.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Payone config in your function:

```
$payoneConfig = Mage::helper('payone_core/config')->getConfigPayment($storeId);
```

In `Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment` you can find all methods which you can call on `$payoneConfig`, e.g. `getAvailableMethods()`. Overwrite `Payone_Core_Model_Config_Payment` the Magento way if you want to add more functionality.